# iOS 7.1.1 Safari browser messing up with online/offline status

Tags: ios, html, offline-browsing

I have a cross browser online/offline test for a webpage designed to work on multiple browsers.
It works with the free indicators :

- event listener on window
- event listener on document.body
- polling of the navigator.onLine variable

http://jsfiddle.net/3mMfG/

```
window.addEventListener("online", function() {
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "online";
}, false);

window.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "OFFLINE";
}, false);


document.body.ononline = function() {
    document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = "online";
};
document.body.onoffline = function() {
    document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = "OFFLINE";
};


setInterval(function () {
    if (navigator && navigator.onLine) 
        document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = "online";
    else
        document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = "OFFLINE";
}, 500);
```

I used this piece of code on several iOS, Android or laptop browsers with success.

On a specific iOS 7.1.1 device it does not work. I have tested it on other iOS 7.1.1 devices with success, but on this specific one, when turned offline, after a few seconds (~5) all indicators come back to "online".

I have tested on multiple devices but was only able to reproduce the problem on this specific one. I turn it offline using the "flight save mode" button, no wifi nor bluetooth is allowed but after a few seconds, the online event is triggered in the browser and the navigator.onLine variable turns to true... Weird...

If you have any clue about what's happening, I will be delighted to exchange with you.

Please if you test the page with *your* device, do not hesitate to comment to let me know if it works on *your* device. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the network settings in the iOS Settings app corrected this behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

For me it was giving error on iPhone 8 plus Simulator iOSv11. I had to Turn On "Allow HTTP Services" located as shown below in order to get navigator.onLine return true -

Under settings -> Developer -> "Allow HTTP Services"